# События ввода на инпут

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, мне нужно отслеживать текст ввода т.е. мгновенная события на символов. Например пользователь нажал "1" сразу показывает "1":

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" /> <span id="errmsg"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quantity").keypress(function (e)  
    { 
        $("#errmsg").html($("#quantity").val());     
    });
  });
</script>
```

У меня не так не получается, нажимаешь на "1" пусто, потом еще "3" а тебе показывает "1", потом еще "5" а тебе показывает "13", хочу чтоб сразу показывал,
 туплю реально, что посоветуете?

Comment: а как обновлять страницу после каждого ввода чтоб прочитать кукис в php а с поля ввода я загоняю туда в кукис
и нужно обновить чтоб считалось и отобразилось в переменной php?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Да все очень просто, давайте пробовать `keyup`ом`:

**html:**

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" /> <span id="errmsg"></span>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function(){
  var Value = $('#quantity').val();
  $('#errmsg').empty();
  $('#errmsg').text(Value);
});
```

Пробуйте :)

Comment: ОООО, вы гений), Спасибо!!!

Comment: @bemulima, пожалуйста) Всегда готов помочь)

Comment: Только чуток оптимизировать бы:

    $('#quantity').keyup(function(){ 
        var Value = $(this).val();
        $('#errmsg').text(Value);
    });

Comment: а есть фича, чтобы и на вставку мышью реагировал?

Comment: Вот [тут найдете](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.8B.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.BC.D1.8B.D1.88.D0.B8) какие угодно события. Вместо **keyup** ставите понравившееся и дело в шляпе.

Comment: @heleg - paste я вот [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/38698#201492) использовал , а для модерновых браузеров есть евент input.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('#quantity').on('input', function () {
    var msg = $(this).val();
    $("#errmsg").text(msg);
});
```